# C# Designing RDLC report properly in WinForm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, reportviewer

[image]
Above this i have a screenshot of my currently working RDLC, Here I have two red arrows which specify my two questions. First, How can i change the Column Header color ? and lastly How can i fit my row values inside this table. I hope someone would be able to help me.

PS: My dataset here is my Database in Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I change the Column Header color?**

Choose the first row of tablix and in *Properties* window or *Report Formatting* toolbar, change `BackgroundColor`.

**How can i fit my row values inside this table?**

You cannot. You just can turn on/off the growing functionality by setting `CanGrow` to true or false. But the columns doesn't support auto-size width.